# ASP.NET dropdownbox options disappear when moving mouse in IE8 & IE9

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, linq-to-entities, internet-explorer-9, webusercontrol

This problem only occurs in Internet Explorer 8 & 9

I have two dropdowns (cboCountry & cboPractice) inside a web user control that are bound to entity datasources. When clicking on the control (either the box itself or the arrow) the list of options appear but only if the mouse stays stationary, the second the mouse is moved the options disappear again.

Has anyone experienced this before and if so what was the cause & solution?

I initially thought it may have something to do with the update panel it was sitting in and so tried commenting it out but unfortunately it made no difference.

There is code fired when cboCountry's value has changed (see below) but only to show a separate panel with a region dropdown in it. Autopostback is set on cboCountry but not on cboPractice and this issue is occurring on all dropdowns in that web user control.

```
Protected Sub cboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboCountry.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            If cboCountry.SelectedValue = 211 Then
                pnlStates.Visible = True
            Else
                pnlStates.Visible = False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Any help with this would be appreciated - you can see the issue here (IE9) [The Lawyer Network](http://www.thelawyer-network.com)

Comment: It's typical that once I had posted this it stopped happening. It definitely was happening so if anyone else has experienced this intermittently I would appreciate your comments.

Comment: That's a client side issue (javascript). It seems there's an onchange event attached -> setTimeout delay is 0. I haven't used the update panel in a long time (been scripting things myself, etc.) so check on either the update panel or perhaps if you are using ACT, settings for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the second the mouse is moved the options disappear again.

Not exactly.

What happens is that when you move the mouse outside the element that contains the dropdown, or over the dropdown options, the options are hidden. As long as the mouse is over the select element itself, or over the dark box containing the select, the options are not closed.

So, you should look for an event that you have hooked up to the containing element.

Comment: I've not hooked up any events myself, the events that have been hooked up will be asp.net events. I have noticed that in the source of IE9, the options aren't closed properly.

Comment: @jQueryMike: How did you examine the source in IE9? When I look at the source (using View source), the options are closed properly.

Comment: I looked at it using developer tools, each option in the select doesn't have a closing option or forward slash at the end.

Comment: I have now managed to fix the problem. I'm not exactly sure why, but the typekit font that was applied to the select control seemed to cause the issue. By taking it off the issue went away - put it back on again and it came back. I'll contact typekit and see if they know the reason for this happening.

Thanks again for your input & assistance!

Comment: @jQueryMike: The developer tools doesn't show the source, it shows the elements, so there isn't any ending tags anywhere. Strange that a font would have that effect...

Answer (score 0):

Removing
`select { font-family: 'Open Sans'; }` 
from my css avoided this IE 8 bug for me